# Pymongo, Motor memory leak

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, python-asyncio, tornado

Background: I use tornado + motor, and found the mem_usage increase.

Then I code the test.py. The db.tasks "size" : 12192854 (10+M). After one minute, MEM USAGE / LIMIT is  1.219GiB / 8GiB

env:

- python 3.7.5
- motor 2.5.0 (2.1.0 before upgrade)
- multidict 4.7.5
- pymongo 3.12.0

Here are my code

```
import os
import gc
import time
import logging
import asyncio
import uvloop
import pdb
import pymongo
import base64
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
from guppy import hpy
from motor import motor_asyncio


mongo_auth = 'xxxxx='
runtime_mongos = arch_mongos = {
    "host": f"mongodb://{base64.b64decode(mongo_auth).decode()}@" + ','.join(
        [
            "1xxx:27024",
            "2xxx:27024",
            "3xxx:27024",
        ]),
    "readPreference": "secondaryPreferred"
}
table = motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(**runtime_mongos)["db"]["tasks"]

async def get_data():
    return await table.find().sort([
            ("priority", pymongo.ASCENDING),
            ("start_uts", pymongo.ASCENDING),
        ]).to_list(None)

async def test():
    while True:
        a = await get_data()
        print(len(a))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        gc.collect() # no use!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

Comment: `a` is still holding a reference to the data. And `a` is still in scope when you run the garbage collector so it doesn’t get cleaned up. Does it work as you expect if you add `del a` before calling `gc.collect()`.

Comment: @dirn 'a' will hold some mem, but in fact, I code "await get_data()", mem still increase. Finally, I try "del a", the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the python process has a lot of threads, then I get a clue about the motor 'ThreadPoolExecutor'.

code in motor 2.1:

```
if 'MOTOR_MAX_WORKERS' in os.environ:
    max_workers = int(os.environ['MOTOR_MAX_WORKERS'])
else:
    max_workers = tornado.process.cpu_count() * 5

_EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers)
```

I set MOTOR_MAX_WORKERS=1 and the mem_usage keeps in low level.

I deploy my project in docker.But, the cpu of the container is not exclusive.I guess this is the reason of 'max_workers' is irrational.

My fault...